# Django with oracle error. ORA--0001: Message -1 not found

Tags: python, ajax, django, oracle, django-models

I have a problem with a Django project using Oracle for quite some time which i cannot solve.This is my first work on oracle database but i will try to explain as best as i can. I have developed a tool in my work  for users to be able to massively update records(Just Update).The data are presented and filtered using ajax.
There is also an oracle procedure created by someone else than inserts some records to the tables.
But often the tool stop working throwing the following:

```
DatabaseError: ORA--0001: Message -1 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=ORA
```

I tried everything and i searched everywhere for months but with no luck.
At first i saw that the sequence nextval was behind max ID by using triggers and sequences and changed that for the id to get nextval when the procedure inserts records ensuring unique id but after that max ID and nextval are ok but the error persists.We looked about constraint violation during insert but i don't think that's the case cause the primary key - unique id is incremented correctly and we dont get error from oracle logs.

I know ora--0001 is unique key constaint violation i've been searching and trying things for months but i don't know which constraint is violated since i get "Message -1 not found".

The error logging comes from the application logging system we also created a logging in oracle but nothing appears there and after talking with the DBA's the say that no error appears to logs and the dont know what is happening it's like it doesnt exist but i still get ORA--0001.

The only constraints that exists are the Primary key (ID) and ID is not NULL:

```
SITES_HALTED_REASONS_PK Primary_Key                     ENABLED NOT DEFERRABLE  VALIDATED   USER NAME           12/06/17    DAS SITES_HALTED_REASONS_PK     
SYS_C0011733    Check   "ID" IS NOT NULL                    ENABLED NOT DEFERRABLE  VALIDATED   GENERATED NAME          24/05/17
```

I am on dead end here for months i read about unique index and making connstrains defferable but i am not so sure that is the way and i will solve the problem. The thing is that i do only search with ajax and update which is not logical to get unique key violation.Also from the logging system i get the error is caused on ajax post or posting empty Query on update or something similar. The following are couple of examples of the first error logs:

```
1.    return Database.connect(conn_string, **conn_params)
DatabaseError: ORA--0001: Message -1 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=ORA

Request repr(): 
<WSGIRequest
path:/mass_update/reasons/sites/halted/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'__session:0.66375524560864:': 'http:',
 'csrftoken': 'ThbibARdilkyc3g6izASpAHBen1mm4Yr'},

2.   

Internal Server Error: /mass_update/reasons/sites/halted/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/mass_update/mass_update/views.py", line 96, in sites_halted
    return render(request, 'sites_halted.html', {'form': form} )
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 67, in render
    template_name, context, request=request, using=using)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 99, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 210, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 217, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 92, in render
    output = force_text(output)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 92, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(s)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 390, in <lambda>
    klass.__unicode__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_unicode(self))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 537, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/widget_tweaks/templatetags/widget_tweaks.py", line 28, in as_widget
    html = old_as_widget(widget, attrs, only_initial)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 593, in as_widget
    return force_text(widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs))
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 513, in render
    options = self.render_options(choices, [value])
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py", line 539, in render_options
    for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 1107, in __iter__
    for obj in queryset:
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 838, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/dashboard/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 214, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(conn_string, **conn_params)
DatabaseError: ORA--0001: Message -1 not found;  product=RDBMS; facility=ORA



Request repr(): 
<WSGIRequest
path:/mass_update/reasons/sites/halted/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{'__session:0.66375524560864:': 'http:',
 'csrftoken': 'ThbibARdilkyc3g6izASpAHBen1mm4Yr'},
META:{'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/var/www/idash',
 'CONTEXT_PREFIX': '',
 u'CSRF_COOKIE': u'ThbibARdilkyc3g6izASpAHBen1mm4Yr',
 u'CSRF_COOKIE_USED': True,
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/var/www/idash',
 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': 'csrftoken=ThbibARdilkyc3g6izASpAHBen1mm4Yr; __session:0.66375524560864:=http:',
 'HTTP_HOST': 'idash.victus.gr',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://idash.victus.gr/mass_update/reasons/sites/halted/',
 'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS': '1',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36',
 'PATH_INFO': u'/reasons/sites/halted/',
 'PATH_TRANSLATED': 'redirect:/index.php/sites/halted/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '172.27.66.138',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '61077',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'REQUEST_SCHEME': 'http',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/mass_update/reasons/sites/halted/',
 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/root/mass_update/dashboard/wsgi.py',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'/mass_update',
 'SERVER_ADDR': '172.31.128.20',
 'SERVER_ADMIN': 'root@localhost',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'idash.victus.gr',
 'SERVER_PORT': '80',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5',
 'UNIQUE_ID': 'WX@X3lek1z3wHZH8gb8pAAAAABA',
 'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'idash.victus.gr|/mass_update',
 'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',
 'mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',
 'mod_wsgi.input_chunked': '0',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',
 'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '80',
 'mod_wsgi.process_group': 'mass_update',
 'mod_wsgi.queue_start': '1501534174566045',
 'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',
 'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',
 'mod_wsgi.version': (3, 4),
 'wsgi.errors': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7fc3e830fdf0>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x7fc3e83187b0>,
 'wsgi.input': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7fc3e830fdb0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': True,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def sites_halted(request):
    #view for halted sites
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReasonAndCategoryForm(request.POST)
        id_list = request.POST.getlist('checkbox')
        d = {}
        print id_list
        info = request.POST['info']
        username = request.POST['username']
        tt = request.POST['tt']
        actions = request.POST['actions']
        comments = request.POST['comments']

    #idd = request.POST.get('checkbox')
    #print idd
    if form.is_valid():
        if form.cleaned_data['reason']:
            reason = str(form.cleaned_data['reason'])
            d['reason'] = reason
        if form.cleaned_data['category']:
            category = str(form.cleaned_data['category'])
            d['category'] = category


        if info:
            d['info'] = info
        if username:
            d['username'] = username
        if tt:
            d['tt'] = tt
        if actions:
            d['actions'] = actions
        if comments:
            d['comments'] = comments

        try:
            SitesHaltedReasons.objects.filter(id__in=id_list).update(**d)
        except Exception as e:
            #print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[1]
            # print str(e)
            logger.error(e.message)
        #   raise

else:
    form = ReasonAndCategoryForm()
#sites = SitesHaltedReasons.objects.all()[:30]
return render(request, 'sites_halted.html', {'form': form, 'name': request.user.username} )


def sites_down_ajax(request):
sites = SitesDownReasons.objects.all()[:40]
isnull_sitename=True
isnull_sitenumber=True
isnull_info=True
isnull_reason=True
isnull_category=True
isnull_tt=True
isnull_username=True
isnull_spares=True
isnull_pending=True
isnull_actions=True
isnull_comments=True
isnull_lastupdate=True
isnull_opco=True
isnull_gsm=True
isnull_umts=True
isnull_lte=True
isnull_region=True
isnull_county=True
isnull_totalaffected = True
isnull_oosend = False

if request.method == 'POST':
    sitename = request.POST['sitename']
    sitenumber = request.POST['sitenumber']
    page = request.POST['page_number']
    region = request.POST['region']
    info = request.POST['info']
    oostart = request.POST['oostart']
    oosend = request.POST['oosend']
    reason = request.POST['reason']
    category = request.POST['category']
    tt = request.POST['tt']
    username = request.POST['username']
    spares = request.POST['spares']
    pending = request.POST['pending']
    actions = request.POST['actions']
    comments = request.POST['comments']
    lastupdate = request.POST['lastupdate']
    opco = request.POST['opco']
    gsm = request.POST['gsm']
    umts = request.POST['umts']
    lte = request.POST['lte']
    region = request.POST['region']
    county = request.POST['county']
    totalaffected = request.POST['totalaffected']
    null_reasons = request.POST['chk_reason']
    null_oosend = request.POST['chk_oosend']



    isnull_sitename = True if sitename == '' else  False

    isnull_sitenumber = True if sitenumber == '' else False

    isnull_reason = True if reason == '' else False

    isnull_category = True if category == '' else False

    isnull_info = True if info == '' else False

    isnull_tt = True if tt == '' else  False

    isnull_username = True if username == '' else False

    isnull_spares = True if spares == '' else False

    isnull_pending = True if pending == '' else False

    isnull_actions = True if actions == '' else False

    isnull_comments = True if comments == '' else False

    isnull_lastupdate = True if lastupdate == '' else False

    isnull_opco = True if opco == '' else False

    isnull_gsm = True if gsm == '' else False

    isnull_umts = True if umts == '' else False

    isnull_lte = True if lte == '' else False

    isnull_region = True if region == '' else False

    isnull_county = True if county == '' else False

    isnull_totalaffected = True if totalaffected == '' else False




else:
    sitenumber = ''

if sitename == '' and sitenumber == '' and region == '' and reason == '' and category == '' and info == '' and username == ''  and \
tt == '' and spares == '' and pending == '' and actions == '' and comments == '' and opco == '' and gsm == '' and umts == '' and \
lte == '' and  region == '' and county == '' and totalaffected == '' and oostart == '' and oosend == '' and not null_reasons and not null_oosend:
    sites = SitesDownReasons.objects.all().order_by('-oostart')

else:
    print null_reasons

    if null_reasons:
        isnull_reason = True
        reason = "##"

    if null_oosend:
        isnull_oosend = True

    try:
        sites = SitesDownReasons.objects.filter( ((Q(info__isnull=True) | Q(info__icontains=info))) & (Q(info__isnull=isnull_info) | Q(info__icontains=info)), \
            ((Q(reason__isnull=True) | Q(reason__icontains=reason))) & (Q(reason__isnull=isnull_reason) | Q(reason__icontains=reason)),
            ((Q(category__isnull=True) | Q(category__icontains=category))) & (Q(category__isnull=isnull_category) | Q(reason__icontains=category)),
            ((Q(username__isnull=True) | Q(username__icontains=username))) & (Q(username__isnull=isnull_username) | Q(username__icontains=username)),
            ((Q(tt__isnull=True) | Q(tt__icontains=tt))) & (Q(tt__isnull=isnull_tt) | Q(tt__icontains=tt)),
            ((Q(spares__isnull=True) | Q(spares__icontains=spares))) & (Q(spares__isnull=isnull_spares) | Q(spares__icontains=spares)),
            ((Q(pending__isnull=True) | Q(pending__icontains=pending))) & (Q(pending__isnull=isnull_pending) | Q(pending__icontains=pending)),
            ((Q(actions__isnull=True) | Q(actions__icontains=actions))) & (Q(actions__isnull=isnull_actions) | Q(actions__icontains=actions)),
            ((Q(comments__isnull=True) | Q(comments__icontains=comments))) & (Q(comments__isnull=isnull_comments) | Q(comments__icontains=comments)),
            ((Q(lastupdate__isnull=True) | Q(lastupdate__icontains=lastupdate))) & (Q(lastupdate__isnull=isnull_lastupdate) | Q(lastupdate__icontains=lastupdate)),
            ((Q(opco__isnull=True) | Q(opco__icontains=opco))) & (Q(opco__isnull=isnull_opco) | Q(opco__icontains=opco)),
            ((Q(gsm__isnull=True) | Q(gsm__istartswith=gsm))) & (Q(gsm__isnull=isnull_gsm) | Q(gsm__istartswith=gsm)),
            ((Q(umts__isnull=True) | Q(umts__istartswith=umts))) & (Q(umts__isnull=isnull_umts) | Q(umts__istartswith=umts)),
            ((Q(lte__isnull=True) | Q(lte__istartswith=lte))) & (Q(lte__isnull=isnull_lte) | Q(lte__istartswith=lte)),
            ((Q(county__isnull=True) | Q(county__icontains=county))) & (Q(county__isnull=isnull_county) | Q(county__icontains=county)),
            ((Q(totalaffected__isnull=True) | Q(totalaffected__icontains=totalaffected))) & (Q(totalaffected__isnull=isnull_totalaffected) | Q(totalaffected__icontains=totalaffected)),
        #Q(reason__icontains=reason), \
        sitename__icontains=sitename, sitenumber__icontains=sitenumber, region__icontains=region, oosend__isnull=isnull_oosend ).order_by('-oostart')

    except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e.message)

    if oostart:

        oostart_date = oostart.split()[0].split('-')
        year = oostart_date[0]

        month = oostart_date[1]
        day = oostart_date[2]
        try:
            sites = sites.filter(oostart__year=year, oostart__month=month, oostart__day=day).order_by('-oostart')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e.message)
        list(sites)

    if oosend:
        oosend_date = oosend.split()[0].split('-')
        year = oosend_date[0]
        month = oosend_date[1]
        day = oosend_date[2]
        try:
            sites = sites.filter(oosend__year=year, oosend__month=month, oosend__day=day).order_by('-oostart')
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(e.message)
        list(sites)

########## Pagination ###############
paginator = Paginator(sites, 20)

#page =  request.GET.get('page')
#print page
p = Page(sites, 20)

if page != None:
    pages = p.pages_to_show(int(page))
else:
    pages = p.pages_to_show(1)


try:
    sites = paginator.page(page)

except PageNotAnInteger:

    sites = paginator.page(1)

except EmptyPage:

    sites = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


context = {'sites':sites, 'pages': pages}



return render(request, 'sites_down_ajax.html', context)
```

This is a piece of the code but its similar for all tables

Can anyone that have worked with oracle give me some help or hints or any suggestion what might be causing this error or how to locate it because it is very confusing and i am having a really hard time to even identify.

Thank you

Comment: You're not getting an `ORA-00001: unique constraint violated`, you're getting an `ORA- (negative 0001)`. That's why there's two dashes. An exception with error code -1 is being raised, and the Oracle client is complaining that it can't find a description for that exception. This is a custom error code, not a built-in Oracle error.
My guess is that this is a client-side error, and your DBA is right that the server doesn't know about it. Maybe your client lost its db connection. Can you increase your logging in Django / cx_oracle?

Comment: First of all i want to thank you for your knowledge not knowing about neggative errors i was convinced it was an oracle i couldnt find an explanation like yours after doing a lot of search.I've included whole logging in the 2nd example if that is what you mean by incresing logging  i noticed a get_new_connection and i thought maybe connection was lost and trying to connect but as i told i thought it was an oracle error.That also explains in a way that after restaring apache everything came back to normal and the fact that the error appear after months of working without an error.

Comment: Hmm, this is out of my depth for Python debugging. :) You might change the tags on your question to get some Python experts to take a look at it.